# IIF or IF statement in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, iif

I am trying to write a **IIF statement** in **Tableau** to check if a condition passes. If it fails the condition, I want it to show `"No values"` rather than filtering out the row.

Given below is the IIF statement I am using:

```
IIF(([Average monthly count] > [Today]),[Average monthly count],"No values in the range")
```

Comment: I'm assuming [Average monthly count] and [Today] are floats, your fails condition needs to be the same data type, not a string.

Comment: ok so what is the problem with the IIF statement?

Comment: What results are you getting and how do they differ from what you want to see?

Comment: It throws an error when I run this. But if I change it to  

IIF(([Average monthly count] > [Today]),[Average monthly count],1,0) it works fine. Any idea how to pass string.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, in Tableau isn't possible to return two different data types in `IF` or `IIF` statements, so if you really need to pass a string like "no values in range", you must return a string in true case. This can be done using the function `STR` as follows:

```
IIF(([Average monthly count] > [Today]),STR([Average monthly count]),"No values in the range")
```

Another option may be just return `NULL` in false case.

```
IIF(([Average monthly count] > [Today]),[Average monthly count],NULL)
```